# Fix iframe height after multiple submits

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i have an Website with an Formular where every time the user hits the submit-button, a iframe will load the requested Content (an Image created by an PHP-script) and the iframe will adapt to the Contents width. i used this code:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("resultframe");
var doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.document || frame.contentWindow.contentDocument;
var height = $(doc).height();
$(frame).animate(
    {height: height  + "px"}
)
```

so the code checks the Contents height and resizes to that height. but after i requested a large Image and a small Image i discovered that the Contents height ($(doc).height() or doc.body.scrollHeight) will not Change to the new Contents height, the height only gets bigger when the new Content is bigger than the one before (it never becomes less). so is there any way to solve this Problem? i also had AJAX in mind, but you cannot use it to fetch Images, unless you use the base64-encoding, but that would increase the amount of recieved Content.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This css and javascript you can use for all iframes on your page. it resizes the iframes whenever content is changing, you may replace `.load` with `.change` too.

css:

```
iframe {border:0; overflow:hidden;}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").load( function () {
        var c = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument);
        if (c.document) d = c.document;
        var ih = $(d).outerHeight();
        var iw = $(d).outerWidth();
        $(this).css({
            height: ih,
            width: iw
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: sry, i tried your code, but it didnt work. outerHeight Returns the same as height, the Problem still remains. by the way, i tested this on Internet Explorer, maybe this says something to you.

Comment: The only difference is, that I am not using .animate() but .css(), but this should be not important

Comment: maybe we dont have the same query Version, i use this one: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: me too, 1.10.2, did you try with .change instead of .load ?

Comment: even if i do that, it remains the same